# How to display column name as data in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, exec

I have a query like this.

```
EXEC('SELECT FirstName, LastName,' + @Subject + ' FROM Student')
```

I have to display one more column which is first 2 letters of the dynamically selected column name "Subject".
I have tried using SUBSTRING function as below but it fetches first 2 letter of the data. Instead I want to fetch first 2 letters of the column name. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```
EXEC('SELECT FirstName, LastName,' + @Subject + ', SUBSTRING('+@Subject+',1,2)  FROM Student')
```

Comment: You have to be careful because this kind of solution are risky from the point of view of SQL injections.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - can you please show us how it it is possible to do a SQL inject here ?

Comment: Try this `SET @Subject = 'p2AAA; SELECT 1 AS SqlInjection; --'; EXEC(...);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @SUBJECT_SPLIT VARCHAR(10)
SET @SUBJECT_SPLIT = SUBSTRING(@subject,1,2)
EXEC('SELECT FirstName, LastName,' + @Subject + ', ''' + @SUBJECT_SPLIT + '''
FROM Student')
```

I gives correct values with 3 inverted commas around +@SUBJECT_SPLIT+. I have no idea why it worked with 3 inverted commas, it will be of great help if someone can it.

Answer (score 3):

You can move the substring outside:

Assuming the column will be physically present in the table:

```
DECLARE @SUBJECT_SPLIT VARCHAR(10)
SET @SUBJECT_SPLIT = SUBSTRING(@subject,1,2)
EXEC('SELECT FirstName, LastName,' + @Subject + ',' + @SUBJECT_SPLIT + ' FROM Student')
```

Assuming the column will not be present physcially:

```
DECLARE @SUBJECT_SPLIT VARCHAR(10)
SET @SUBJECT_SPLIT = SUBSTRING(@subject,1,2)
EXEC('SELECT FirstName, LastName,' + @Subject + ', '' AS ' + @SUBJECT_SPLIT + ' FROM Student')
```

Comment: Say @SUBJECT_SPLIT is p2 then it searches for column name "p2". Since there is no column as "p2" , it throws error

Comment: Because `@SUBJECT_SPLIT` is a string you need to use a string delimiter: `= '''' + SUBSTRING(@subject,1,2) + ''''`.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I am sorry but I didn't get it. Can you please give an example.

Comment: If the value of `@subject` variable is `p2_InvoiceDate` then the value of `@SUBJECT_SPLIT` is `p2` and the SQL statement will be `EXEC('SELECT FirstName, LastName,p2_InvoiceDate,p2 FROM Student'`. In this case SQL Server thinks that `p2` is a column and because there is no `p2` column the OP gets above error. The final SQL statement should be `EXEC('SELECT FirstName, LastName,p2_InvoiceDate,'p2' FROM Student'`.

Comment: From the question, I believe the assumption is the first 2 columns would exist in the table (otherwise it would definitely throw an error); the answer is based on that assumption; If no column is physically present in that name, then you must use @subject_split as alias name and execute the sql statement dynamically:

Comment: The EXEC statement is in a loop and based on the condition '@SUBJECT' has different value every time. That's why I need to use SUBSTRING function to fetch first 2 letters of the @SUBJEC and hence I can't hard code 'p2' in the SELECT statement. 
Let me explain the structure of the table I want from the select statement:
First 2 columns (Firstname and Lastname) are already present in the table. Third column is a dynamically selected column and in fourth column I want to display first 2 letters of the third(@SUBJECT) column.